# Instalação do Angular

Tags: angular

Pessoal estou precisando de ajuda !!

Estou tentando instalar o angular, sendo que, a instalação não sai desta tela abaixo. O que pode ser? obs: já tenho o NodeJs instalado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: mano, já me ocorreu algo parecido e eu achei a solução aqui mesmo, tenta isso:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011546/npm-install-error-rollbackfailedoptional

Answer (score 1):

Cada projeto possui suas próprias dependências que precisam ser instaladas:

instalar o npm:

```
apt install npm
```

verificar se foram instalados:

```
nodejs -v

npm -v

ng version
```

Atualizar:

Node estável:

Instalar o nodejs:

```
 apt install nodejs
```

ou

```
 npm cache clean -f

 npm install -g n

 n stable
```

Angular CLI Remover versão anterior:

```
 rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng
```

instalar o CLI:

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Atualizar:

```
 npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Complementando sua resposta, como ele usa PowerShell talvez seja mais interessante o uso de um administrador de pacotes para o Windows, como o [`Chocolatey`](https://www.eunati.com.br/2017/08/chocolatey-gerenciador-de-pacotes-windows.html) ou o  [`OneGet`](https://www.geekzilla.com.br/microsoft-oneget-gerenciador-pacotes-windows-10/), que são dois dos inúmeros exemplos de administradores de pacotes, ou [passar a usar um shell em conjunto com o Windows](https://terminalroot.com.br/2018/03/como-usar-o-shell-bash-no-windows.html) como mostrado em diversos tutoriais pela rede